# Returning list of files based on creation date

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

I'm just starting out with bourne shell scripting and trying to write a script that will take in two command line arguments: a directory and a file. I want to compare the creation date of the file with those in the directory and print all older files, and then print a count of all newer files.

This is the code I've attempted so far, but I know it's not recognising the directory properly.

```
#!/bin/sh

directory=$1
file=$2
x=0

for f in $directory
do 
  if [ $f -ot $file ]
  then
    echo "$f"
    x='expr $x+1'
  fi
done

echo "There are $x newer files"
```

Any tips would be thoroughly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Step 1 would be making sure you're using a file system that actually stores file creation date. Most don't. The `ctime` is not "creation time", but "change time", and there are activities post-creation that will modify that timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` command provides options to search for files based on timestamps. What you want to achieve can be done without the use of a loop:

```
# Search for files with modification time newer than that of $file
find $directory -newermm $file

# Search for files with modification time older than that of $file
find $directory ! -newermm $file
```

Please refer https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html for more details.

However, if you are learning shell scripting and want to write your own script, here are a few suggestions:

1. For iterating over files in a directory, you can use:

   ```
   for f in "$directory"/*
   ```
2. As far as I know, `-ot` compares modification times (and not creation times). For that matter, I doubt if Linux provides creation time of files.
3. Incrementing `x` (count of newer files) should be done in an `else` clause. I would prefer `x=$((x+1))`, which is supported in all POSIX-compliant shells.
4. Caveat: Iterating using `"$directory/*` will not recurse into sub-directories. `find` will recurse into sub-directories unless you specify the `-maxdepth` option.

Comment: Thanks heaps for clearly this up for me. Do you know if there's a way to do the same as find, but count the files rather than printing each one out?